# Inserting csv data into complex hive table

Tags: hadoop, hive

Hive version is 0.13, Hive table description is as follows:

```
CREATE  TABLE temp
(
customer_id int,
sales_item array<struct<item_id:int,item_name:string,item_price:decimal(10,2)>>,
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '|';
```

my csv file is:

```
10,1|watch|300
```

How to insert into hive table...I tried and my ouput is as follows:

```
10  [{"item_id":1,"item_name":null,"item_price":null}]
```

Not inserting any value for item_name and item_price.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current documentation of the delimiters is problematic. I'll update it later on.
It is actually not **fields**, **collection items** and **map keys** but nesting levels 1,2, and 3 and there are additional levels that are not mapped by the `create table`  syntax.

```
create external table temp
(
    customer_id     int
   ,sales_item      array<struct<item_id:int,item_name:string,item_price:decimal(10,2)>>
)
row format delimited
fields terminated by ','
map keys terminated by '|'
;
```

---

```
select * from temp
;
```

---

```
+-------------+------------------------------------------------------+
| customer_id |                      sales_item                      |
+-------------+------------------------------------------------------+
|          10 | [{"item_id":1,"item_name":"watch","item_price":300}] |
+-------------+------------------------------------------------------+
```